# Antd RadioGroup onChange fires before radio value is set

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using ant design and I'm having trouble with a radio group. It seems to me like the onChange handler on the RadioGroup fires when a radio button is clicked, but before the value of that radio button is set.

Here is some sample code

```
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
console.log('field value', getFieldValue(name)); // previous value, not changed value.
};

const component =
getFieldDecorator &&
getFieldDecorator(name, {
  initialValue: value,
  rules: formatValidations(validations)
})(
  <RadioGroup name={name} onChange={handleChange}>
    <Radio value={1} key={1}>1</Radio>
    <Radio value={2} key={2}>2</Radio>
    <Radio value={3} key={3}>3</Radio>
  </RadioGroup>
);
```

When this `handleChange` function runs, the field value is wrong. The first time I click radio 1, the value is undefined. Then I click 2, the value is 1. In other words, the onChange event is triggered, but the the value of the radio button is not yet set, I am only able to get the previously set value. Can anyone see anything wrong with my implementation?

Also, `e.target.value` is the expected changed value (it does not match the getFieldValue value).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `antd` support recommends using `onValuesChange` in `Form.create()` https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/20418

I found this workaround that works for me:

```
<Radio.Group
 onChange={(e: RadioChangeEvent) => {
   form.setFieldsValue({ yourRadioFieldNameFromGetFieldDecorator: e.target.value }, () => {
      handleChange();
   });
 }}
>
```

The callback ensures that field value is set.

Comment: where is `RadioChangeEvent` defined?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus It is type of event parameter of `onChange` function of `<Radio.Group >`. If you're using VSCode, right click on `<Radio` and `Go to definition` (or `F12` button) and there you'll find it in the `onChange: (e: RadioChangeEvent) => void;`

Comment: I 'm on Emacs and I don't have the most sophisticated setup imaginable. Can you supply the import statement please. E.g.: `import {RadioChangeEvent} from 'antd'` is not working.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Here it is `import { RadioChangeEvent } from 'antd/lib/radio'`

Answer (score 1):

You should really use `e.target.value` if you want the value immediately. since the value is not set yet (to the antd form yet) at the moment you click the radio.(the field needs to pass setStatus, setfeedback etc)

if you really want to use getFieldValue, you can do the setTime strick

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(this.props.form.getFieldValue('radio-group')), 0)
```